# JS callback for tap tools in bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, callback, bokeh, interactive, tap

I want to make an interactive graph. In the first graph, using the "tap" widget, the values "x" shown by the "hover" widget are selected, the values d(:,x) are plotted on the second graph. When you click the "tap" widget again to another place in Graph 1, graph 2 is updated. But I do not know how to write a callback to the "tap" widget.
An example of what I am looking for is this

[image: here]

the presented code creates two graphs, but does not update the second graph:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
import os
from numpy.lib.function_base import select
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, TapTool


N = 500
x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
d = np.sin(xx)*np.cos(yy)
len_d=len(d)

plot1 = figure(tooltips=[("x", "$x{0}"), ("y", "$y"), ("value", "@image")],
             plot_height=350, plot_width=400,title="Graph 1 d",tools = "tap")
plot2=figure(plot_height=350, plot_width=400, title="Graph 2 d(tap selection(x))", 
              tools="pan,box_select,crosshair,box_zoom,reset,save,wheel_zoom,hover") 

#f = d[:,select]
lines = plot2.line(x = 'x', y = 'y', source = ColumnDataSource({'x': d[0] , 'y': -np.arange(len_d)}))
lines.visible = False
plot1.x_range.range_padding = plot1.y_range.range_padding = 0

data = dict(
    image=[d], pattern=['smooth ramp'],
    x=[0], y=[5], dw=[20], dh=[10]
)

code = '''if (cb_data.source.selected.indices.length > 0){
            lines.visible = true;
            var selected_index = cb_data.source.selected.indices[0];
            lines.data_source.data['x'] = d[selected_index]
            lines.data_source.change.emit(); 
          }'''

cds = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
plot1.image(source=cds, x=0, y=-len(d), dw=len(d[0]), dh=len(d),palette='Spectral11', level="image")
plot1.grid.grid_line_width = 0.5
plot1.select(TapTool).callback = CustomJS(args = {'lines': lines, 'd': d}, code = code)
plots = row(plot1, plot2)
show(plots)
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: To be honest I am not quite sure if I unterstand what your are trying to do, but if you are looking for linking two figures, check out [customjs for selections example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-selections) from the `bokeh` documentation. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @mosc9575 yes, I'm trying to link two graphs, the first graph is image(matrix "d") on the second graph to get "d(:,selection).

Comment: And how should your connection work? What should happen in the left plot, which reaction do you want in the right one? Could you please update your question.

Comment: @mosc9575 ok i will update my question

Comment: I tried your code and I get this warning `WARNING:bokeh.core.validation.check:W-1000 (MISSING_RENDERERS): Plot has no renderers.` This is the right one. Did you see that [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-selections) a renderer is added, which then is changed by the callback?

Comment: i don't understand this error, bokeh creates two graphs for me, and is it a renderer? Is there a CustomJS that selects values ​​in chart 1?

Comment: A renderer can be a [`plot2.line()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html?highlight=figure#bokeh.plotting.Figure.line) or a [`plot2.circle()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html?highlight=figure#bokeh.plotting.Figure.circle), but you only created `plot2` but never added a renderer. But you have assigned a `line` and an image to `plot1`. `plot2` is still empty.

Comment: Please read this [introduction](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_1.html).

Comment: @mosc9575 I updated the code, now there are renderers for both plots. I can't write the code for the JS callback yet. Which would update graph 2 for me when I use tap on graph 1. My opinion is that the problem is in the indices in the code, I am using variable X to update graph 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which selects data from the image.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
output_notebook()

N = 500
x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
d = np.sin(xx)*np.cos(yy)
len_d=len(d)

data = dict(
    image=[d], pattern=['smooth ramp'],
    x=[0], y=[5], dw=[20], dh=[10]
)
# plot 1
cds_p1 = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
plot1 = figure(
    plot_height=350,
    plot_width=400,
    title="Graph 1 d",
    x_range =(0,500),
    y_range =(-500, 0),
    tooltips=[("x", "$x{0}")]
)
plot1.grid.grid_line_width = 0.5
plot1.image(
    source=cds_p1,
    x=0,
    y=-len_d,
    dw=len_d,
    dh=len_d,
    palette='Spectral11',
    level="image"
)
# plot 2
y_index = -np.arange(len_d)
cds_p2 = ColumnDataSource(
    {'x': d[0] , 'y':-np.arange(len_d) }
)

plot2=figure(
    plot_height=350,
    plot_width=400,
    title="Graph 2 d(tap selection(x))",
    x_range =(-1,1),
    y_range =(-500, 0),
    tools="") 
plot2.line(x = 'x', y = 'y', source=cds_p2)

# important JS part
callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(cds_original=cds_p1, cds_p2=cds_p2),
    code="""
    // console.log('Tap event occurred at x-position: ' + cb_obj.x)
    
    const data = cds_original.data
    const next = cds_p2.data
    var xpos = Math.round(cb_obj.x)
    
    console.log((xpos-1)*500)
    console.log(data['image'])
    
    var x = []
    for(var i=xpos; i<500*500; i+=500){
        console.log(data['image'][0][i])
        x.push(data['image'][0][i])
    }
    next['x'] = x
    console.log(next)
    cds_p2.change.emit()
""")
plot1.js_on_event('tap', callback)

plots = row(plot1, plot2)
show(plots)
```

I think this is not the final solution but maybe this brings you one step closer.

Comment: I have a question about the JS code, if the size of the data `d` changes, how can I substitute the new values?

Comment: You can pass this value using a new variable in `CustomJS` like `CustomJS(args=dict(_len_d=_len_d))`.